# How to get the index of first error in a range of cells?

Tags: excel

I have a range of cells some of which may have an error. On another cell, I want the index of the cell in the range for which the first time an error occurs.

For example if my range of cells is: 1,2,3,error,error,4,5, I want the output to give me 4 because thats the index of the first error.

I was trying to use a iferror and if but I haven't found a solution yet. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a non-CSE solution to this, but here's an option:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(A1:A7),0)
```

Confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]